# How to run OptaPlanner CVRP in Java

Tags: java, optaplanner

I would like to run the CVRP examples in optaplanner in java using my own xml files. My problem is that I cant figure out how to supply the xml files and to which method. If i instantiate a Solution and supply the xml config.

How do I tell my solution where to get the UnSolved xml files? I would prefer to have the xml files as a parameter.

Some code snippet below:

```
public static void run(){
        SolverFactory<VehicleRoutingSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml");
        Solver<VehicleRoutingSolution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

        VehicleRoutingSolution mySolution = new VehicleRoutingSolution();


        mySolution.getCustomerList();
        mySolution.getVehicleList();
        mySolution.getDepotList();


        //mySolution.setMyPlanningEntity(myPlanningEntity);

        solver.solve(mySolution);

        VehicleRoutingSolution bestSolution = (VehicleRoutingSolution)solver.getBestSolution();
        System.out.println("Best solution: " + (bestSolution));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `SolutionDao` object and then use it's VRP implementation using XStream to load the "unsolved" XML files. The format will need to be the same one that OptaPlanner uses for it's VRP XML input files.

```
public class TestApp {

    public void solveFromFile(File vrpXmlInputFile) {
        SolverFactory<VehicleRoutingSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml");
        Solver<VehicleRoutingSolution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

        VehicleRoutingDao solutionDao = new VehicleRoutingDao();
        VehicleRoutingSolution solution = solutionDao.readSolution(vrpXmlInputFile);

        solver.solve(solution);

        VehicleRoutingSolution bestSolution = solver.getBestSolution();
        System.out.println("Best solution: " + (bestSolution));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usage: TestApp [pathToVrpXmlInputFile]");
        }

        TestApp app = new TestApp();
        app.solveFromFile(new File(args[0]));
    }

}
```

Make sure to set the working directory correctly (in my case `......./optaplanner/optaplanner-examples`.